# Determining how late one can show up for an exam

Tags: probability, statistics, exponential-distribution

> A student will go to school for his Final Exam and he will take a bus to school. The time for a bus to arrive at the station follows an Exponential Distribution with a rate of $1$ bus per $10$ minutes. It takes $10$ min for the bus from the station to the school. The student needs to be at school by 8:00 a.m. What is the latest time he must arrive at the bus station so that he is on time for his exam at least $95\%$ of time? (Specifying the time in the format 00:00 a.m)

### My attempt

He must arrive at bus station by 7:50 am

So a bus arrives in $10$ min on average.

$$\begin{align}P(T\le t) &= 1 - e^{-t/10}\\1 - e^{-t/10} &= 0.95\\e^{-t/10}&= 0.05\\t &= -10 \cdot \ln(0.05) \\&= 29.957\text{ min}\\&\approx30\text{ min}\end{align}$$

so he must arrive $30$ min before 7:50 am

so he must arrive by 07:20 am

ANSWER : 07:20 am

I am not sure if my logic is sound in structuring the answer.

Comment: Looks good to me. You have used the cumulative distribution function in your first line, so you should mention that.

Comment: More precisely, he should leave by 7:20:2.56.  Some students absolutely *would* want to have those extra 2.56 seconds.